# Suppose A & B are disjoint events with probability $P\{A\}= 0.4$, $P\{B\}=0.5$

Tags: probability

Find

(a) $P\{A \cup B\}$

(b) $P\{A^c\}$

(c) $P\{A^c \cap B\}$

This is what I have right now:

(a) $P\{A \cup B\}=0.4+0.5=0.90$

(b) $P\{A^c\}= 1-0.4=0.60$

(c) $P\{A^c \cap B\}= (0.6)\cdot(0.5)=0.30$

Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Does "disjoint" mean "mutually exclusive" or "independent"?

Comment: It would be independent

Comment: Then you should be wrong: $P(A\cap B)$ should be $0.4×0.5=0.2$. The rest you can work out yourself.

Comment: Oh okay I see my mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, $A$ and $B$ are indepentent (not disjoint). Be careful, the two things are not equivalent.

Anyway, if $A$ and $B$ are independent, your answer to (a) is not correct.
Indeed,
 $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).$$ Since $A$ and $B$ are independent $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Hence $P(A\cup B)=0.4+0.5-0.2=0.7$.
On the other hand, (b) and (c) are correct.

Answer (score 1):

For **any** two events $A$ and $B$, $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$

If $A$ and $B$ are **mutually exclusive**, then $P(A\cap B)=0$ and thus $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$$

If $A$ and $B$ are **independent**, then $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ and thus $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)$$

Thus (a) is wrong, while (b) and (c) are correct.